# Assign the output of command to variable

Tags: linux, bash

I have to cut the string after the white-space and store the value before white-space. My example script is show below

```
tString="This is my name"
echo $tString | cut -d' ' -f1
```

output:

> This

Now I want to assign this output value to the variable. My script is

```
tString="This is my name"
var=$($tString | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

It shows error.Error message is

> This: command not found

Iam new to bash shell script. Anyone Knows how to do this.

Comment: var=$(echo $tString | cut -d' ' -f1)

Comment: Besides, you don't need this complex command. `read var unused <<< $tString` will also serve the purpose.

Comment: @anishsane,thanks both command works

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `read var unused <<< "$tString"` , else it may give errors on some bash'es...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add an `echo`:

```
tString="This is my name"
var=$(echo $tString | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

(Also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560118/assign-the-output-of-command-to-variable#comment23791506_16560118) 2 seconds before I posted my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Using [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion):

```
tString="This is my name"
var="${tString%% *}"
echo "$var"
This
```